# Generic way to add field to 'readonly_fields' and and 'fields' Djnago admin with decorator or Mixin

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to have some generic way to append str to fields ('fields', 'readonly_fileds') to the django admin the ideal way is Mixin or the decorator? When I tried some ways I had recursion or errors.

There are two ways that I tried.

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.


class DistributedAdminMixin():
    pass
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DistributedAdminMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        import pdb
        pdb.set_trace()

        readonly_fields = self.readonly_fields.copy()
        readonly_fields.extend(['id_to_str'])
        self.readonly_fields = readonly_fields

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        import pdb
        pdb.set_trace()
        print(1)
        if 'fields' in kwargs:
            fields = kwargs.get('fields') + ('id_to_str', )
        else:
            fields = self.flatten_fieldsets(self.get_fieldsets(request, obj))

        super(DistributedAdminMixin, self).get_form(self, request, obj, **kwargs)

    def get_fields(self, request, obj=None):

        fields = super(DistributedAdminMixin, self).get_fields(request, obj)
        fields.append('id_to_str')

        readonly_fields = super(DistributedAdminMixin, self).get_readonly_fields(request, obj)
        # super(DistributedAdminMixin, self).readonly_fields = readonly_fields.append('id_to_str')

    #     return fields

def distributed_admin(wrapped):
    class WrappedClass(wrapped):

        def get_fields(self, request, obj=None):

            fields = WrappedClass.get_fields(request, obj)
            fields.append('id_to_str')

            return fields

    return WrappedClass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to use this in multiple admin models. This should work:

```
class ExtraFieldMixin:
    def get_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        fields = list(super(ExtraFieldMixin, self).get_fields(request, obj))
        return fields + ['extra_field']
```

Same for `readonly_fields`, but you have to override `get_readonly_fields` method.

Remember that you need an attribute or method in your django model or in your admin model called `extra_field`. You could have it in your Mixin too:

```
class ExtraFieldMixin:
    # Previous code
    def extra_field(self, obj):
        return str(obj.id)
```